# Sass using string to call var

Tags: sass

The need is to call a var by a name that is built.  Here is what i have

```
$font-size-small:3rem;
$line-height-base:2rem;

$font-size-h1:1rem;
$font-size-h2:2rem;
$font-size-h3:3rem;
$font-size-h4:4rem;
$font-size-h5:5rem;
$font-size-h6:6rem;



@for $i from 1 through 6 {
    $tag: h#{$i};
    $var: font-size-h#{$i};
    $sized: (100% * $font-size-small / #{$var});

    #{$tag}.small, .#{$tag}.small, #{$tag} small {
        font-size: $sized;
    }
}
```

it  output like

```
h1.small, .h1.small, h1 small {
  font-size: 300% / font-size-h1;
}

h2.small, .h2.small, h2 small {
  font-size: 300% / font-size-h2;
}

h3.small, .h3.small, h3 small {
  font-size: 300% / font-size-h3;
}

h4.small, .h4.small, h4 small {
  font-size: 300% / font-size-h4;
}

h5.small, .h5.small, h5 small {
  font-size: 300% / font-size-h5;
}

h6.small, .h6.small, h6 small {
  font-size: 300% / font-size-h6;
}
```

but what i need is

```
h1.small, .h1.small, h1 small {
  font-size: 300% / 1rem;
}

h2.small, .h2.small, h2 small {
  font-size: 300% / 2rem;
}

h3.small, .h3.small, h3 small {
  font-size: 300% / 3rem;
}

h4.small, .h4.small, h4 small {
  font-size: 300% / 4rem;
}

h5.small, .h5.small, h5 small {
  font-size: 300% / 5rem;
}

h6.small, .h6.small, h6 small {
  font-size: 300% / 6rem;
}
```

I'm not finding anything that doesn't use a map.  The issue is that there is alot of these whole styles that are reference as `____-6` where that 6 would be like 1 through 6.  So why not just build the var name and call it.

Comment: Why do you use `$var` inside `$sized` if you don't want its value? To get the output you need use `$i` instead `$var`: `$sized: (100% * $font-size-small / #{$i});`. Otherwise `font-size: size / size` isn't valid syntax in CSS

Comment: Great question, if you add a unit it wouldn't work.   That is why, those have units of `rem` .  I need to call the var with a string of it's name like you would in most other languages.  A kin to JS where `var test="foo"` could be call by `window[ "f" + "00" ]` .  I am making a point that it's a string with that concat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use interpolation in a variable name, another solution is use maps and a function to extract the number of each value to make mathematical operations:

**SASS**

```
$font-size-small: 3rem;
$line-height-base: 2rem;

$map:(
font-size-h1: 1rem,
font-size-h2: 2rem,
font-size-h3: 3rem,
font-size-h4: 4rem,
font-size-h5: 5rem,
font-size-h6: 6rem
);

@function strip-unit($number) {
    @return $number / ($number * 0 + 1);
}

@for $i from 1 through 6 {
    $tag: h#{$i};
    $var: map-get($map, font-size-h#{$i});
    $sized: (100% * strip-unit($font-size-small) / #{$var}  );

    #{$tag}.small, .#{$tag}.small, #{$tag} small {
        font-size: $sized;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
h1.small, .h1.small, h1 small {
  font-size: 300% / 1rem;
}

h2.small, .h2.small, h2 small {
  font-size: 300% / 2rem;
}

h3.small, .h3.small, h3 small {
  font-size: 300% / 3rem;
}

h4.small, .h4.small, h4 small {
  font-size: 300% / 4rem;
}

h5.small, .h5.small, h5 small {
  font-size: 300% / 5rem;
}

h6.small, .h6.small, h6 small {
  font-size: 300% / 6rem;
}
```

**P.S.:** I insist that the syntax for `font-size` is incorrect in CSS.

Comment: :) yes the `font-size` is wrong, i was being lazy lol .. The rub is that there are many vars along the way that have this name scheme so I wanted to be able to just get at any or all that, lets say, end in "-h1" .  Basically how do i access the master list.  I have an idea on making one, but i don't want a program out of scss files lol